# Audit trail when an Opportunity Team Member is added

Tags: email-template, opportunity, variable-names

Our workflow:

- The Account Rep creates an opportunity.
- At the appropriate time, they 'request' a Consultant. This is done in SFDC with a checkbox "Consultant Requested"
- This checkbox triggers an email to a Team Lead who would assign a specific Consultant, based on a number of factors.
- The Team Lead goes to the SFDC Opportunity and adds the chosen Consultant to the Opportunity Team.
- Upon addition to the Opportunity Team, an email is fired to the Consultant to inform them they are assigned.

The Problem:

- Our Account Reps have access to add Team Members to their opportunity (to add executives to their sales opportunity), and will occasionally assign a Consultant to the Opportunity as well.
- Even if it is the correct Consultant, the issue with this is that the Team Lead has to monitor and report assignments.

Some ideas for a solution:

- Can we see who added a team member to the opportunity in some report?

OR

- Can we include in the triggered email some variable that indicates who has added them?

It currently says:

> The following opportunity has a request for a Consultant and has been assigned to you. Please review.
>
> XYZ Account Name
>
> XYZ Opportunity Name
>
> https://company.my.salesforce.com/0060B07899aXoRY

Can we make it say:

> The following opportunity has a request for a Consultant,  and has been assigned to you. Please review.
>
> XYZ Account Name
>
> XYZ Opportunity Name
>
> *Added to Opportunity Team by [Joe Smith]*
>
> https://company.my.salesforce.com/0060B07899aXoRY

Comment: Are you currently tracking the team lead in a lookup on the `Opportunity`, per chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to **Add a Team Member** in Opportunity related list Or **A field(Lookup to User Or simply a Text field)** is being updated for Consultant?

-> If it is adding a Team Member you can get details from CreatedBy/LastModifiedBy from Opportunity Team Member Object

->If you are Updating a field(say lookup to user) you enable History Tracking for this field which will keep track of "who changed the value" & "From what to what it has been changed".

Comment: I needed history tracking. This was the value change that I needed to see. Thank you so much.